# Configure Zabbix monitoring tool on kubernetes cluster in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, zabbix

I am trying to configure zabbix monitoring tool on the top of kubernetes clutser in Google Cloud Platform. 
I followed [the KB](https://gist.github.com/tbernacchi/626a4ded652e2dca4666bc3f2a8b216c) and the zabbix server configured successfully. I have also configured a zabbix agent using [this link](https://github.com/monitoringartist/kubernetes-zabbix/blob/master/dockbix-agent-xxl-daemonset.yaml)
Now I would like to know how my pods running on the cluster can be added to this zabbix server. Seeking your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Used Dockbix Docker images already have preconfigured Zabbix with [auto registration](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/discovery/auto_registration), which should discover your nodes/containers (containers!=pods). I guess you didn't configured sec. groups or DNS names properly.

Comment: Dear Jan Garaj,

Thank you for your quick update. Actually I am new to this technology and I am little bit confused about this.My doubt is  Once I created the pods zabbix-web,zabbix-db, and zabbix-server, Does my zabbix server configuration is completed? Please let me know if I have to do any action in the zabbix server.

Does I need to create the zabbix agent again as a pod? Could you please guide me?

Thank you

Comment: I have configured zabbix and added two pods as host. But getting a warning that  Zabbix agent on pod is unreachable for 5 minutes. Please let me know How can I rectify this.

Comment: Hi, I have configured the zabbix agent correctly and now my pods are listing in zabbix server. But the datas are not fetching. I got the following error from agent logs:
===================
Cannot open metric file: '/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/156acb75044da35d200071019119ac0f7050568cc8cf3713f6937483729c276d/memory.stat'
=============================

can somebody help me on this

Comment: It can be a known issue of used Zabbix module - https://github.com/monitoringartist/zabbix-docker-monitoring/issues

Comment: I have followed the KB. But the issus is that, the specified path in log(/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/docker) is not available in my server.  The server only have the path "/sys/fs/cgroup"
So Does I need to add the specific path in agent. It seems the module tries to detect a wrong path in mycase. my serveris ubuntu and it is in GCP.
Please find the log and advice me if you can identify the problem.

Comment: 13294:20180606:100210.203 Item [Id] found in the received JSON object: 
 13294:20180606:100210.203 Metric source file: /rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/docker/88cf3db208abd423a2bd2c8559cb9309a118b0a3ce060a23d055200645ffe876/cpuacct.stat
 13294:20180606:100210.203 Cannot open metric file: '/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/docker/88cf3db208abd423a2bd2c8559cb9309a118b0a3ce060a23d055200645ffe876/cpuacct.stat', container doesn't run
 13294:20180606:100210.203 Sending back [0]

Comment: root@master# uname -a
Linux master-us-central1-a-kq25 4.13.0-1006-gcp #9-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:13:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 G
NU/Linux

Comment: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay-2fb4e39eff2cfd073d68582148970cf6bf7440b280fa0c6d1
8c65eda59736298-merged.mount

Comment: root@master# ls -lah /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 May  2 05:40 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu -> cpu,cpuacct